# python printing dictionary's value vertically

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary and each item has key and value[0] and value[1]. 
There are multiple entries for value[0] in list, whereas key and value[1] are single value. 
I would like to print value[0] vertically as per output below.

Many thanks!

```
mydict = {
      '1': (['John'], 20),
      '2': (['Jane',
             'Doe'],  21),
      '3': (['Johnny',
             'John',
              'Roe'],  10),
    }



Output:
    Id    Name     Age 
    1     John      20  
    2     Jane      21
          Doe
    3     Johnny    10
          John
          Roe
```

I tired following to get output vertically but unable to get right format.

```
 for k,v in sorted(mydict.iteritems()):
      print k,
      print "\n".join(str(x) for x in v[0])
      print v[1]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
This is an exercise in output formatting; go back to the "Python output tutorial" you should have already found and bring us an honest attempt at coding this yourself first.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick, but based on your code snippet, it appears you're using a 2.x version in which case you will need to change `mydict.items` to `mydict.iteritems` for compatibility purposes.

```
for k,v in sorted(mydict.items()):
    print(k)
    im_a_string = ""

    for i in v[0]:
        im_a_string += i + " "

    print(im_a_string.rstrip())
    print(v[1])
```

which outputs:

```
1
John 
20
2
Jane Doe 
21
3
Johnny John Roe 
10
```

However, if you're simply trying to print the (key:value) pair of your dictionary the following should help... came 2.x vs 3.x compatibility issues apply:

```
my_dict={}

my_dict["im a key"] = "im a value"
my_dict["im another key"] = "im another value"
my_dict

for key,value in my_dict.items():
    print(key + " : " + value)
```

which will give the following output:

```
im a key : im a value
im another key : im another value
```